# How to fix problem with throwing error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, throw

Here is a piece of Node.js code

```
app.get('/cat', function (req, res) {

console.log(req.query.id);

let catID = req.query.id;

res.render('category',{});
con.query(
  'SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = '+catID,
  function (error, result) {
    if(error) throw err;
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
  });
});
```

[image: My problem]

Don't know what is this and how to fix it

Comment: if (error) throw error* ?

Comment: a) you've got a typo in the variable name b) you should handle the error instead of `throw`ing it from an asynchronous callback into nowhere (crashing nodejs) c) you should prevent the error from happing in the first place d) you should fix that SQL injection and use a parameterised query instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving `err` but trying to throw `error`. Use below code.

```
app.get('/cat', function (req, res) {

console.log(req.query.id);

let catID = req.query.id;

res.render('category',{});
con.query(
  'SELECT * FROM category WHERE id = '+catID,
  function (error, result) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
  });
});
```

Disclaimer: **Use parameterized query instead of adding query param to db queries. Current code will cause SQL injection threat.**

Comment: No, absolutely don't use that code. It still has multiple problems.

Comment: @Bergi I tried to point out the problem raised in question only. Which was supposed to be done. Didnt want to concern with parameterized query and all.

Comment: Still, don't recommend to "*use below code*" if it has such egregious security issues. At least mention in a disclaimer that you've fixed only that one problem.

Comment: Thanks! Now don't forget to cast a flag to close the question as a typo :D

Comment: @Bergi which flag you use to flag as type? will use it.

Comment: I am new. Can you pls recommend me some courses to learn node.js? Or how to learn node.js well?

Comment: @Developer Flag -> Needs improvement -> Community-specific -> Was caused by a typo